# How many hydrolox engines had a methane variant?

Tags: engines, russia

Russia, has developed many rocket engine concepts over the years and its noticeable that they already tried liquid methane as a propellant back in the 90s. How many of their cryogenic engines had a liquid methane variant? Have any other countries also developed similar capabilities and tried liquid methane in the past?

Answer (score 4):

According to some [old usenet postings by Henry Spencer now on yarchive](https://yarchive.net/space/rocket/rl10.html), the RL10 was experimentally used with methane:

> > "CH4/O2 offers the second highest Isp (385 s)...  A significant
> >     disadvantage of CH4/O2 is that no flight-rated engine is
> >     currently available; development of one based on Pratt and Whitney RL-10
> >     engine technology would probably take three years and cost
> >     on the order of $30 million."
>
> One reason to be reasonably confident in this low number is that the RL10
>   has already been run on LOX/CH4, with only minor modifications.  That was
>   done only experimentally, and you'd need a bit more work to certify that
>   configuration for production use, but it shouldn't be hard.

According to Clark's *Ignition!* (1972), German rocket pioneer [Johannes Winkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Winkler) experimented with a methane/LOX engine in 1930. Clark also mentions with some horror a 1957 proposal to use pre-mixed methane/LOX as a monopropellant. ("JPL later demonstrated that you could make the mixture detonate merely by shining a bright light on it.") Clark also mentions using methane with other oxidizers:

> Rocketdyne, and TRW, with NASA contracts, as well as NASA itself, have concentrated their efforts on OF2 and the light hydrocarbons: methane, ethane, propane, 1-butene, and assorted mixtures of these. (In most of their motor work, they used a mixture of oxygen and fluorine as a reasonably inexpensive surrogate for OF2.)

Spencer also mentions the RL10 having been fired with FLOX (fluorine-LOX mixture), so it seems probable that Clark is talking about RL10 here as well.